# CodeIgniter 4 validation rule group not found despite being defined in custom validation class

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I’m having trouble with the validation class in CodeIgniter 4. I have defined a custom validation class NoticeValidation with a rule group named noticeUpdate, but when I try to use this rule group in my controller, I get an error that the rule group is not found.

Here is the code for my NoticeValidation class:

```
namespace App\Validations;

use CodeIgniter\Validation\Validation as BaseValidation;

class NoticeValidation extends BaseValidation
{
    public $noticeUpdate = [
        [
            'field' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'rules' => 'required|max_length[100]'
        ],
        [
            'field' => 'date',
            'label' => 'Date',
            'rules' => 'required|max_length[10]'
        ],
        [
            'field' => 'image_address',
            'label' => 'Notice image',
            'rules' => 'required|max_length[255]'
        ]
    ];
}
```

And here is the code where I try to use the noticeUpdate rule group in my controller:

```
$validation = \Config\Services::validation();
$validation->setRuleGroup('noticeUpdate');
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> "noticeUpdate" is not a validation rules group.

I have checked my Validation.php and Autoload.php configuration files and everything seems to be set up correctly. I have also tried clearing the cache, but the issue persists.

Can anyone help me figure out why the noticeUpdate rule group is not being recognized by the validation class?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Should `noticeUpdate` not be `NoticeValidation` ?

Comment: NoticeValidation is a class, and inside the class are multiple validation rules like $noticeUpdate and $noticeCreateNotice @Antony

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, and I’m posting the answer that worked for me.

```
<?php

namespace App\Validations;

use CodeIgniter\Validation\Rules;

class NoticeValidation extends Rules
{
   public $noticeUpdateRules = [
        'noticeUpdate' => [
            [
                'field' => 'title',
                'label' => 'Title',
                'rules' => 'required|max_length[100]'
            ],
            [
                'field' => 'date',
                'label' => 'Date',
                'rules' => 'required|max_length[10]'
            ],
            [
                'field' => 'image_address',
                'label' => 'Image address',
                'rules' => 'required|max_length[255]'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

And here is the code where I'm using the noticeUpdate rule in my controller:

```
$updateRules = new NoticeValidation();
$validationRules = $updateRules->noticeUpdateRules['noticeUpdate'];

if ($this->validate($validationRules)) {
   ............
   ..........
}
```